# Kotlin check if Collection is neither null nor empty

Tags: kotlin, apache-commons

Right now, I am using the following function to do this check

```
if(list.isNullOrEmpty().not()) {
  doSomething()
} else {
  dont()
}
```

To me, I feel there would be a shorter method to achieve the same like `neitherNullNorEmpty()` or just `isNotEmpty()` (current isNotEmpty takes non-nullable list). Something along the lines of `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(list)` which looks cleaner. Right now either I have to add `not()` at the end or "!", which doesn't look right as I feel there should be a single function to do this. Such a function will make the code more concise and easier to read. Am I missing something or Kotlin is?

Comment: I don't believe that `!myList.isNullOrEmpty` is less concise than `neitherNullNorEmpty`

Comment: There is no such function in kotlin, you can create it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

you can custom function for check the list with you anything you want like this

```
private fun List<Any>.neitherNullNorEmpty():Boolean{
        return this.isNullOrEmpty().not()
}
```

then just call

```
    val list = arrayListOf<String>()
    val list2 = arrayListOf<Int>()
    if(list2.neitherNullNorEmpty()){

    }
```